# MCC compiler "Internal Error: Could not determine class of method"

Tags: matlab, mcc

I have Matlab script that I am trying to compile as an executable that will run on a headless server as part of a large batch process. The script calls functions and classes written by several non-programmers (scientists) over the span of more than a decade, and I am having a difficult time getting it to compile.

The script will run in a Matlab instance, but MCC gives me an error that I do not quite understand:

```
Compiler version: 5.1 (R2014a)
Dependency analysis by REQUIREMENTS.
Error using matlab.depfun.internal.MatlabSymbol/proxy (line 405)
Internal1 Error: Could not determine class of method
"/home/me/MyCode/@tsd/Data.m". Number of classes checked:
17.
```

@tsd/tsd.m looks like this:

```
function tsa = tsd(t, Data)

% tsd  Creates tsd object (tsd = class of timestamped arrays of data)
%
% tsa = tsd(t, Data)
%
% INPUTS: 
%       t - list of timestamps - must be sequential, but don't have to be continuous
%       Data - data, possibly an array. If data is n-dimensional, then time should be the FIRST axis.
% OUTPUTS: 
%       tsa - a tsd object
%
% Completely compatible with ctsd.
%
% Methods
%    tsd/Range     - Timestamps used
%    tsd/Data      - Returns the data component
%    tsd/DT        - Returns the DT value (mean diff(timestamps))
%    tsd/StartTime - First timestamp
%    tsd/EndTime   - Last timestamp
%    tsd/Restrict  - Keep data within a certain range
%    tsd/CheckTS   - Makes sure that a set of tsd & ctsd objects have identical start and end times
%    tsd/cat       - Concatenate ctsd and tsd objects
%    tsd/Mask      - Make all non-mask values NaN
%
% ADR 1998, version L4.0, last modified '98 by ADR

% RELEASED as part of MClust 2.0
% See standard disclaimer in ../Contents.m


if nargin == 0
 tsa.t = NaN;
 tsa.data = NaN;
 tsa = class(tsa, 'tsd');
 return
end 

if nargin < 2
  error('tsd constructor must be called with T, Data');
end

tsa.t = t;
tsa.data = Data;

tsa = class(tsa, 'tsd');
```

and the Data.m file:

```
function v = Data(tsa, ix)

% tsd/Data  Retrieves data from tsd
%
%   d = Data(tsa)
%   d = Data(tsa, ix)
%
% INPUTS:
%       tsa - tsd object
%       ix - alignment list (timestamps)
% OUTPUTS:
%       v - the tsa.Data
%
%   if called with alignment list, returns those tsa.Data(ix)
%   if called without, returns complete tsa.Data
%
% ADR 1998, version L4.1, last modified '98 by ADR

% RELEASED as part of MClust 2.0
% See standard disclaimer in ../Contents.m


switch nargin
case 2
   f = findAlignment(tsa, ix);
   v = SelectAlongFirstDimension(tsa.data,f);
case 1
   v = tsa.data;
otherwise
   error('Unknown number of input arguments');
end
```

So the script calling the tsd function runs just find in the Matlab session, but the compiler throws the error described above. This is my first time working with Matlab and I am totally stumped. There is another class with a method named "Data", but that shouldn't cause this problem, could it?

Comment: You say you're trying to compile a script, you mean the wtf thing that generally starts with `clear all; close all; clc` instead of `function [...] = foo(...)` ? ... If so, the compiler does not support working with scripts, you have to turn all of them into functions. NB: Not sure this can be the issue because i guess mcc would have return more appropriate error message in this case.

Comment: @nick topper just to let you know I'm having the same issue under Linux and not under Windows. Which platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and was able to come up with a workaround.

I was facing this problem when I was compiling the MATLAB library using the command

```
mcc -W cpplib:LibName -T link:lib main.m -a './' -d 'dll_destintaion_dir'
```

LibName: DLL name
main.m: MATLAB entry point
dll_destintaion_dir: destination where DLL created will be stored

The error was gone when I compiled using this command instead

```
mcc -W cpplib:LibName -T link:lib main.m -a 'full_path_of_project_folder/*' 
-d 'dll_destintaion_dir'
```

Note: This method does not add folders recursively to the archive. So subfolders have to be added explicitly using another -a flag in the command shown above.